# How do I run a python script from the command line?

Tags: python, package, command-line-interface

I have looked at similar questions on SO and elsewhere but cannot find out why my code fails, I must be missing something fundamental here but I cannot see the issue.
I have a package called `testyfolder` containing an `__init__.py` file and two other simple py files, `funcy.py` and `main.py`.
I cannot run them from the command line?

**Error traceback**

```
C:\Users\...\python
>>>import testyfolder
>>>testyfolder.main()
AttributeError: module 'testyfolder' has no attribute 'main'
```

**main.py**

```
import funcy

if __name__ == "__main__":
    funcy.town()
```

**funcy.py**

```
def town():
    print(' this is funcy town')


def village():
    print('this is funcy village')
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong which is preventing the `main.py` file from running and calling the `funcy` file?

It seems I had to go into the directory where the main and funcy python files where and enter 'python main.py' on the command line, this runs the main.py file and returns 'this is funcy town' as expected'.

It can be further improved by adding the shebang to the top of the main.py file, then you only need to go into the folder from the command line and enter 'main.py'.

Comment: Like the error message actually already tells you, there is no `def main` there so you can't call anything with that name. ("No attribute" means there is also no variable with that name, etc.)

Comment: Yes, I still don't know hot to run the main file though.

Comment: The easiest fix is probably to `def main(): funcy.town()` but then you need to `from testyfolder.main import main`; or you could hack something into `__init__` like `import funcy; main = funcy.town`. This is basic packaging (I agree it's thorny to learn) and probably a duplicate. The fundamental misunderstanding is that there are really two namespaces here.

Comment: @tripleee do you know of anywhere i can learn this, I have followed a few videos but they didn't get very complex, and none mentioned anything other than the __init__ being empty (I didn't know you could enter anything in it tbh). Thank you.

Comment: Google is your friend. https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/

Comment: Its a far more useful friend when you know what you are looking for, thanks again tripleee